# ¿Como bloquear el copiar y pegar en un input?

Tags: html, entrada, text

Tengo un input...

```
<input type="text">
```

¿Como hago para bloquear los comandos (control+c y control+v) y click derecho, copiar o pegar?

Comment: Hola Necroyeti es recomendable revisar [ask], has intentado algo  para resolver el problema?, saludos.

Comment: No, no he intentado nada, de verdad que no tengo ni la menor idea...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Con **JavaScript** nativo podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var myInput = document.getElementById('bloquear');
  myInput.onpaste = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("esta acción está prohibida");
  }
  
  myInput.oncopy = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("esta acción está prohibida");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="bloquear">
```

O con **jQuery**:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#bloquear").on('paste', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Esta acción está prohibida');
  })
  
  $("#bloquear").on('copy', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Esta acción está prohibida');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="bloquear">
```

Answer (score 12):

Usando html, Puedes agregar a tu `<body>`

`oncopy="return false"` para evitar el copiado (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>),

y `onpaste="return false"` para evitar el pegado (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>):

Ejemplo:

```
<body oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false">    
<input type="text">
```

Esta es una demo:

```html
    <body oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false">    
    <input type="text">
    <p>Trata de seleccionar y copiar este texto (Ctrl+c) y pegarlo (Ctrl+v) ...</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay una extensión de chrome que se salta las restricciones al "onpaste" estos métodos no sirven si el usuario la tiene instalada. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-fuck-with-paste/nkgllhigpcljnhoakjkgaieabnkmgdkb

Comment: No corresponde a una respuesta valida ya que no contiene código valido para el proyecto sino el plugin para instalar en el navegador.