# ¿Como validar correctamente un input onkeypress usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

He estado practicando con eventos en javascript, porque ya me cansa colocar onclick, onfocus u otro evento como atributo en las etiquetas HTML y quise compartir este código, ¿se puede mejorar en cuanto a la seguridad o puede ser mas corto?

```js
divKeys=document.querySelector('.keys');
divRegex=document.querySelector('.regex');
document.querySelector('.input').onkeypress = function(e) {
  //console.log(e);
  let keyCodes = RegExp('^(0|[8-9]|13|1[5-7]|28|3[7-9]|40|46|4[9]|5[0-9]|6[5-9]|[7-8][0-9]|90|9[6-9]|10[0-9]|11[0-9]|12[0-3])$');
  let regex = /[0-9]/;
  let tecla = e.keyCode;
  let tecla_final = e.key;
  let cond1 = keyCodes.test(tecla);
  let cond2 = regex.test(tecla_final);
  divKeys.innerText='KeyCodes: '+(cond1==true?'true':'false');
  divRegex.innerText='RegExp: '+(cond2==true?'true':'false');
  return cond1 && cond2 ? true : false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
<br>
<h3>resultado</h3>
<label class='keys'>KeyCodes:</label>

<br>
<label class='regex'>RegExp:</label>
```

Comment: Perdon, que estas intentando validar

Comment: inputs en general.
Pero no se si realmente le haga falta algo.

Comment: Probaste usar una librería de terceros, digo la mayoría de las cosas ya estan hechas, si no es para un caso muy especifico no le veo sentido estar haciendo un propio validador de ese estilo. Prueba [Jquery Mask](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin)

Comment: Bueno, una de las cosas que no he podido hacer es impedir que usando el mouse > click derecho > pegar evite que inserte valores que no están en RegExp.

Comment: wow, necesito usar esa librería.

Comment: esta respondida en otra pregunta lo de [bloquear el copypast en un input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122777/como-bloquear-el-copiar-y-pegar-en-un-input)